# Discord.NET Discord bot web search response

Tags: c#, json, bots, discord

Okay, so I have a Discord Bot that gives basic responses such as:

```
User Input: !Doc status
Bot Output: Online!
```

All basic, but I want to create a response to searches the web and replies with the search results. For example, it's a doctor bot, so I basically want to say:

```
User Input: !Doc symptoms Cough, Runny Nose, Sore throat
Bot Output: You may be experiencing the common viral infection.
```

But I want it to search a site like WebMD and get the results of the user's input of symptoms and reply with what the site says it's possible results.

The Discord bot uses C# and json, so to create a simple command it's as follows:

```
    // The command the user types for this specified response.
    [Command("Symptom")]

    public async Task Sympton()
    {
        // Bots response
        await ReplyAsync("What symptoms are you currently having?");
    }
```

The problem I'm having is I have no idea how I would go about searching a site for the users inputted response and somehow get the response back of the possible illnesses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ApiMedic-Api](http://apimedic.com/). You need to make an account on the site in order to do this. 
They also have Code-Examples on [Github](https://github.com/priaid-eHealth/symptomchecker), where you probably find everything you want.